# Get data out of Java string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string of the following type:

```
{{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}}
```

where a to h can be any string (which doesn't contain `{` and `{`).

What is the most efficient way of getting just `a`, `b`, `c`,..`h` in an `Array` maybe in `Java`?

Scanning through each character doesn't seem to be a good solution to me.

Comment: Have you tried split function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [`String::substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [`String::split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

**Be careful scaping `}` and `{` characters in `split` pattern**.

```
String s = "{{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}}";
s = s.substring(2, s.length()-2);
String[] ss = s.split("\\}\\{");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

**INPUT:**

```
String s = "{{addaa}{grbwergb}{afñsljidhfWAc}{FFWEFWFd}{SGGRAERe}{ghetthsaf}{rweggwrgg}{wrgRGAEh}}";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[addaa, grbwergb, afñsljidhfWAc, FFWEFWFd, SGGRAERe, ghetthsaf, rweggwrgg, wrgRGAEh]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use regular expressions, like so:

```
String text = "{{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)([^{}]*)(?=\\})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

String[] result = new String[8];
for(int i = 0; i < result.length && matcher.find(); i++) {
    result[i] = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

The output was:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

It is important to note that this solution, at least in its current form, will only find a maximum of 8 strings. If you need a more dynamic solution refer to Jordi Castilla's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String originStr = "{{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}}";
String tmpStr = originStr.replace("{{", "").replace("}}", "");
String[] resultArray = tmpStr.split("\\}\\{");
```